Need to make a weird shape for quarter circle
I am making a map with roads.  One of these roads has a 90 degree turn in it.  I made by making a round bevel. Now I need to make an inverse of it for the walkway next to it. Something like this:


Hello, so you could just extrude the vertices of the round edge?

it helps (you and us) if you would tell us, if you are a Blender beginner, intermediate or pro. Because depending on that the comments and answers will be different. And if you are a beginner, you might even don't understand the comments or answers.

i am a beginner in Blender.

Select the first edge of the curve, and then extrude it far out on the Y axis.  (It might be the X axis for you)


Enable snapping and set it to edges:

Extrude the other edge, and snap it to that new face you made earlier.

Now snap the edge that is too long back to the other one, so you have a nice square.
Select everything while in edit mode, hit M and Merge by distance.  (This is just good practice.  It looks like the 90-degree angle has one edge, but it actually has two, from both extrusions.  This merges them into one.)
Select all the parts shown, and hit SHIFT + d to duplicate it.  Then, use p to separate it by selection.

Yay!

To finish it off, delete the extra faces from your original shape.
Select the edges of your sidewalk, (You can use ALT + Click to select an entire loop of edges at once), and Fill in the face.  You also need to do this on the underside.

Hope this his helpful!
(Forgetting to disable snapping can lead to a lot of frustration later.  You can use SHIFT + TAB to toggle snapping.)
